Javascript onfocusout Uncaught TypeError
I have page where I want to force user to input certain pre defined values in a text box and if he does not inout those chosen values, focus is shifted back to that text box till user chooses one of the values. My code looks like this


function onloadfunction() {
  alert("On Load!");
  var sourcDealerId = document.getElementById("dsatext");
  sourcDealerId.focus();
}

function getFocusBack() {
  alert("Welcome Back Focus!");
  var sourcDealerId = document.getElementById("dsatext");
  if ((sourcDealerId.value != "DEALER") || (sourcDealerId.value != "MARKET")) {
    alert("Text Box Values::" + sourcDealerId.value)
    alert("Valid Values are DEALER OR MARKET only")
    sourcDealerId = "";
    sourcDealerId.focus();
  }
}
<input type="text" id="dsatext" onfocusout="getFocusBack()" />
<input type="text" id="othertext" />



However when i run this code I encounter following errors

Even when I input values like DEALER or MARKET, it still alerts the message Valid Values are DEALER OR MARKET only
Fcous is not shifted to first text box when i input wrong values
I get the message Uncaught TypeError: sourcDealerId.focus is not a function in console . It pertains to line of code inside getFocusBack() function


sourcDealerId = "";  ->  "".focus()  -> strings don't have a focus event

If this is for some sort of security "please type this in", or as a coding exercise, then fine - but if it's for any sort of application where you have users that need to fill this in, then please consider using radio buttons or a select with 3 options (default being blank so they have to select something).

Your || logic is incorrect.  If it's "not A or not B" means if it's A, it's not B, so will fail.  Needs to be "not A and not B" -> &&  - or use "not (A or B)"

sourcDealerId = "";
sourcDealerId.focus();


I get the message Uncaught TypeError

Well, yeah.  You set sourcDealerId to a string, and strings do not have a focus method.  Perhaps you wanted
sourcDealerId.value = "";

although if I were the user, I would be positively enraged that the system was erasing my answer.

Oh that was a typo and that removes errors at S No 2 and 3 but error at Sno 1 still remains unsolved. Even when if type DEALER or MARKET ,  if expression evaluates true and i still get message alid Values are DEALER OR MARKET only

You have (sourcDealerId.value != "DEALER") || (sourcDealerId.value != "MARKET"). The || means “or”.  If you meditate on the meaning of the word “or”, the answer will come to you.

I modified the code and put the else condition


if((sourcDealerId.value === "DEALER") || (sourcDealerId.value === "MARKET") ){
                                      //alert("Text Box Values::"+sourcDealerId.value)
                                      alert("Correct Value");      
                             }
                             else{
                                alert("Valid Values are DEALER OR MARKET only");
                                sourcDealerId.value="";
                                sourcDealerId.focus();
                             }



